# The graph of $f$

Tags: analysis

My question is kind of silly but I’m wondering why in my textbook, their is a drawing of a function $f$ whose graph continues after the limit point into the $x_0 +\delta$ region of the interval. I don’t understand why this is so. I think about $\frac{1}{x}$ whose graph ends at $L=0$ not having a graph that extends into the $x_0 +\delta$ region. I would appreciate some help with this small misunderstanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If a function is defined on let say an interval $(a,b)$ and that $x_0 \in (a,b)$, $f$ may have a limit $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)=L$ which enables to  draw the graph of $f$ on the left and right side of $x_0$. This will be the case by the way for any $x_0 \in (a,b)$ if $f$ is supposed to be continuous on $(a,b)$.

Comment: What if I choose $x_0=b$ then shouldnt there only be a graph to the left of $x_0$?

Comment: @Fredsaffiyre For sure!

Comment: And isnt it was necessary that $x_0=L$ in the definition. If this is the case shouldn’t the graph always be to the left of $x_0$?

Comment: $L$ is in the codomain of $f$. So there is absolutely no reason for having $x_0=L$.